# Angular JS - How can i animate on model change?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i'm trying to do a nice fadeout+fadein transition when the currentVertical changes.
in knockout it was so simple but i can't figure it out here. please help.

the following code displays a UL list which is "bound" to a pricings array in the $scope.currentVertical when an LI element is clicked, the $scope.currentVertical is changed and the UL list updates accordingly. This works fine, but i would like the entire #container div to fade out and fadein when $scope.currentVertical is changed. Please help...

My html:

```
<body>
    <h1>Pricing Poll</h1>
    <div ng-controller="VerticalsController">
        <div id="container">
            <h2>{{currentVertical.title}}</h2>

            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="pricing in currentVertical.pricings">
                    <a ng-click="currentVertical.selectPricing(pricing)">{{pricing.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

my javascript:

```
function VerticalsController($scope) {

  $scope.verticals = [
    {
        title:'internet',
        pricings: [
            {
                name: 'netvision',
                monthly: 23
            },
            {
                name: 'hot',
                monthly: 33
            },
            {
                name: '012',
                monthly: 28
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        title:'cellular', 
        pricings: [
            {
                name: 'cellcom',
                monthly: 20
            },
            {
                name: 'pelephone',
                monthly: 30
            },
            {
                name: 'orange',
                monthly: 25
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        title:'banks', 
        pricings: [
            {
                name: 'leumi',
                monthly: 20
            },
            {
                name: 'poalim',
                monthly: 30
            },
            {
                name: 'benleumi',
                monthly: 25
            }
        ]
    }];

    $scope.selected = [
    ];

    $scope.currentIndex = 0;
    $scope.currentVertical = $scope.verticals[0];

  $scope.selectPricing = function(pricing) {
    $scope.selected.push(pricing);
    $scope.currentIndex++;
    $scope.currentVertical = $scope.verticals[$scope.currentIndex];
  };

  /*$scope.remaining = function() {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo) {
      count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
    });
    return count;
  };*/
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use custom or create directives to start advanced DOM manipulation like animations.

Here's a fiddle with the animation you requested, I use the `visible` variable on scope to trigger fading and the $timeout service to only change the selectedItem when fadeOut, it could be improved to pass a timeout and a callback as a directive option...

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g/Bs66R/1/

**JS:**

```
function VerticalsController($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.verticals = [{
    title:'internet',
    pricings: [{
      name: 'netvision',
      monthly: 23
    },
    {
      name: 'hot',
      monthly: 33
    },
    {
      name: '012',
      monthly: 28
    }]
  },
  {
    title:'cellular',
    pricings: [{
      name: 'cellcom',
      monthly: 20
    },
    {
      name: 'pelephone',
      monthly: 30
    },
    {
      name: 'orange',
      monthly: 25
    }]
  },
  {
    title:'banks',
    pricings: [{
      name: 'leumi',
      monthly: 20
    },
    {
      name: 'poalim',
      monthly: 30
    },
    {
      name: 'benleumi',
      monthly: 25
    }]
  }];

  $scope.selected = [
  ];

  $scope.currentIndex = 0;
  $scope.currentVertical = $scope.verticals[0];

  $scope.selectPricing = function(pricing) {
    $scope.selected.push(pricing);
    $scope.currentIndex++;
    $scope.visible = false;

    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.currentVertical = $scope.verticals[$scope.currentIndex];
      $scope.visible = true;
    }, 1000);
  };

  $scope.visible = true;
}

var fadeToggleDirective = function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.uiFadeToggle, function(val, oldVal) {
        if(val === oldVal) return; // Skip inital call
        // console.log('change');
        element[val ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut'](1000);
      });
    }
  }
}

angular.module('app', []).controller('VerticalsController', VerticalsController).directive('uiFadeToggle', fadeToggleDirective);

angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);    angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Pricing Poll</h1>
<div ng-controller="VerticalsController">
  <div id="container" ui-fade-toggle="visible">
    <h2>{{currentVertical.title}}</h2>

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="pricing in currentVertical.pricings">
        <a ng-click="selectPricing(pricing)">{{pricing.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you set ui-fade-toggle to `visible`? Can't you just set it explicitly to `visible` like so `$scope.$watch('visible', function() {})` since `$scope.visible` isn't about to be changed any time soon.

Comment: Directives usually don't rely on naming conventions in the parent scope, so you can use several time the same directive in the same scope (one bound to visible1 and another to visible2 for example).

Comment: This is a good but deprecated approach, as Angular now supports animations natively using a new directive called ngAnimate.

Comment: ngAnimate doesnt seem to have support for slideUp/Down for a container element, therefor you directuve is still relevant http://jsfiddle.net/jv4cf6ex/

Answer (score 9):

I recommend you use the new [ngAnimate](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) directive provided in the AngularJS Core.

Read more [here](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html)

Comment: ngAnimate doesnt seem to have support for slideUp/Down for a container element, therefor you directuve is still relevant http://jsfiddle.net/jv4cf6ex/