# fade out and in (animate) when changing model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building simple query system.
I'm able to display questions one by one, but I'd like to add transitions when I change questions.

I've build Plunker to show my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/svaWMRCy8P8xtMvmIEBA?p=preview

Idea is to fade out div containing question with answers and fade in new question.

I've searched over SO and found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775751/angular-js-how-can-i-animate-on-model-change), but in comments I found info that this method is deprecated.

I've tried using directive from one of questions:

```
.directive('uiFadeToggle', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(element);
      scope.$watch(attrs.uiFadeToggle, function(val, oldVal) {
        if (val === oldVal) return; // Skip inital call
        // console.log('change');
        element[val ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut'](1000);
      });
    }
  };
})
```

but all the time I get this error:

> element[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)]
>   is not a function

How can I animate my model change? Ideally I'd like to use CSS only approach.

EDIT:
My [current solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpcejDyvvJpscQCRrXjq?p=preview) is using [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/), but if there is a better way please add it as answer.

Comment: have you tried using `ngAnimate` with the `ng-enter` CSS classes? @see http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html

Comment: @BettySt thank You for link, I didn't tried it yet, but I'll do that.

Comment: Describe what you are trying to do with this statement: `element[val ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut'](1000);`.

Comment: @georgeawg this is from answer to question I linked to. This is fiddle showing it: http://jsfiddle.net/g/Bs66R/1/

Comment: OK I understand.  That Fiddle uses jQuery 1.8.3. You are attempting to invoke the jQuery functions `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` which are not part of the AngularJS JQLite. Using CSS3 is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation using ng-if coupled with ng-animate. The animations are done using the css classes.

http://plnkr.co/edit/zVLdeQSELkATvC2ltvQG?p=info

```
div class="question-slide animate-switch" ng-animate=" 'animate' " ng-if="idx === questionIndex">
```

The animation between the questions are controlled by the css classes

```
.animate-switch.ng-animate {
    transition: all cubic-bezier(.25, .46, .45, .94) .5s;
}

.animate-switch.ng-leave {
    opacity: 1
}

.animate-switch.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}

.animate-switch.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0
}

.animate-switch.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1
}
```